# Controlling apt-get headers

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have multiple machines out in the field and want to have unattended upgrades, which seems supported by apt-get. However, I want to update different hosts to different versions, e.g. return different Packages.gz files, I think. But inspecting the http-headers sent from apt-get I see this:

```
Content-Length: 
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)
Host: localhost:9991
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type:
```

There is no information who sent the request. I understand this is great for the common usecase, but is there any way to configure apt-get to send e.g. a JWT token in the `Authorization` header?

Comment: You could check the ip address of the requesting machine

Comment: ah, yes. But aside from this? Let's say I'd rather use a JWT token for secutry reasons?

Comment: You can configure apt-get to use a proxy, and then setup a proxy server on your main instance that can only connect to your file-server. A proxy server has a username and password

Comment: yeah, that's pretty much what I'm doing right now. So then the I have a line in my sources.list like so "deb https://user:pass@foo.bar/ xenial main" . This is not optimal as there is a lot of book-keeping with these passwords. (we've got 100s of machines out) Instead I would like to pass a token in the header if possible, hence the question.

Comment: Have you considered using ssh keys to restrict access to your repo? You could then use the ssh key received to identify the user. https://debian-administration.org/article/513/Restrict_Access_To_Your_Private_Debian_Repository

Comment: yes, I _have_ considered that. It's an excellent suggestion. I've two worries for this. Firstly I'm worried I'll set it up in such a way the machine is exposed to attacks allowing terminal access. Secondly, firewalls commonly blocks out port 22, while http & https remains open.

Comment: I am reluctant to give out the bounty as this does not really answers the question, although it's a great suggestion. One answer would be: "No this is not possible, I have checked the apt sources - Use a workaround like a proxy instead"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible directly, but I can see 2 ways you could work around it:

1) Proxy

2) Server Managing System

## Proxy

You could setup a proxy on each managed server which adds the headers you want before forwarding the requests, so from the managing server side your requests have the required headers. For this you could either use a prebuilt proxy, or use [this](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#setup-a-stand-alone-proxy-server-with-proxy-request-header-re-writing) code as a starting point.

## Server Managing System

As an alternative option, you could use a system like Landscape, which have the following features.

- You can manage all your servers from one web UI, or using the provided API
- You can set update rules
- You can push new packages to servers or sets of servers
- You can run scripts on managed servers
- You can have emails sent automatically and packages applied automatically when you have security flaws affecting your servers.
- You can check server status and information

It is free for up to 10 servers, the setup instructions are [here](https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem)

**Edit:**

Having checked the [source](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/2920e9428e26004f90a1f1ea86f07850b2204f85/methods/http.cc) it seems it is not possible to set custom headers at this point, only the following headers seem to be set:

- Host => Server Host name
- Cache-Control => Used for caching
- Accept => The type of response to send
- Range => Used to request a set amount of data
- If-Modified-Since => Used to only get updated data
- Proxy-Authorization => Used for proxy connection login
- Authorization => Used for username / pass auth
- User-Agent => Says what software is used

If you really wanted you could always hide your auth payload in the User-Agent header, but that is not adding a new header as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We've got like 500 machines out there, looking to scale these up now. Landscape would cost us like $3000 /mo already now... :-/

Comment: You'll probably want to use the proxy option then, just have a little proxy on each box, and add the header there, you could even use NGINX like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching#setting-or-resetting-headers)

Comment: yeah, possibly. Right now I'm just using http://user:pass@repo.com for now and that get's the job done also.

Comment: reluctant to give out the bounty as this does not really answers the question, although it's a great suggestion. One answer would be: "No this is not possible, I have checked the apt sources - Use a workaround like a proxy instead".

Comment: Refined to directly answer question at the start of the answer

Comment: Added list of all changeable headers based on source code

Comment: hold on, I  _do_ want t set the `Authorization` header. That seems promising. Do what extend is the contents of this header tweakable?

Comment: It only supports username|password basic auth .   Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65178/discussion-between-jrtapsell-and-vidstige).

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated, see https://samhassell.com/apt-cant-see-sources-try-changing-the-user-agent/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the JWT, but you can for sure add a client cert based authentication which could help much in securing your packages, if that is your main concern.

> apt-get install apt-transport-https

and get the configuration setup

```
Acquire::https::packagedomain.name.com::Verify-Peer "false";
Acquire::https::packagedomain.name.com::Verify-Host "false";
Acquire::https::packagedomain.name.com::CaInfo "/certs/ca.pem";
Acquire::https::packagedomain.name.com::SslCert "/path/clientcert.pem";
Acquire::https::packagedomain.name.com::SslKey  "/path/clientkey.pem";
```

on the nginx side enable the following directives

```
         "ssl_client_certificate",
         "ssl_verify_client",
```

Comment: Interesting! Where do I plop that config? How do I ensure someone else's clients cert is also accepted? Seems to me no ties to a specific cert or chain on server side...

Comment: You can use client cert to secure the package repository so non other than the approved clients can access the package, to set up a client side authentication, you need to create a client cert and key with a local private ca and use nginx(or any other web server of your choice) to have a client cert based auth enabled. Refer http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi and https://www.aptly.info/doc/overview/ for more details